# Representation dimension of $Aus(K[x]/(x^n))$

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $A_n$ be the Auslander algebra of $K[x]/(x^n)$. Is the representation dimension of $A_n$ known? For $n \leq 3$ the algebra is representation-finite and thus the representation dimension is 2. For $n \geq 4$ it is either 3 or 4 but I did not find anything in the literature on that.